# Why Apache IoTDB prompted "tsfile is empty or incomplete" while the resource file is complete?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am now trying to load the tsfile of Apache IoTDB Version 0.13.3 into Version 1.1.0, and a message prompted: Msg: 701: .. tsfile is empty or incomplete. The output information of IoTDB server prompted: Invalid input: 24. I also checked the corresponding resource file, and this tsfile has a resource file with the same name, which means the "incomplete" message should not appear.

What may be the reason for this problem?